# avoid duplicate in ssrs without using Previous method

Tags: reporting-services

Can any one tell me how to avoid the duplicate values in the ssrs report without using the Previous() method.

Thank You

Comment: but why you don't want to use previous? I think there is no other option to do in SSRS report. you can avoid it by dataset.

Comment: You could group your dataset.